# Win 10 21H2 Update stopped file sharing

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, file-sharing

I have desktop Win10 Home and Win10 Pro computers that are hard wired to my router on the same "home" network. File sharing via network drive mapping has always worked OK. After the Pro computer was updated to 21H2 (build 19044.1348 and Feature Pk 120.2212.3920.0), file sharing no longer worked. For several hours, on the Pro computer, following basic networking setup instructions, I made several changes and tried to do them one at a time with reboots in between. Eventually, in: system properties > computer name > network ID, I found a setting to indicate this was a home style network. Then file sharing across the two computers worked again.
The problem is that I lost track of all the other settings I changed. So, my question is: with a feature update like 21H2 what are the most likely settings that caused file sharing to stop working. Besides the Network ID setting, what should I check first and perhaps avoid losing hours of time and making some setting changes I might regret later?

Comment: “what are the most likely settings that caused file sharing to stop working.” - Far to many to list but considering, 21H2 like the (21H1, 20H2, and 20H1) are all entitlement updates which means outside of specific features surrounding WSL very little has changed since 20H1

Comment: “what are the most likely settings that caused file sharing to stop working.” - Far to many to list   .....  Agree, and without knowing the machine, I offered 3 broad categories of checking with the most likely need to be (C) Repair Install.

Comment: OK, thanks guys - I was hoping there were some known issues with this update as regrards the problem I had.  That doesn't appear to be the case.  If this happens again, I'll follow John's suggestions and review all the normal settings that might affect file sharing.  Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Windows 10 20H2 running here and File Sharing continues to work.

**(A) Make sure of the following basics:**

Private Network connection; Network Discovery, File and Print Sharing, and Password Protected Sharing ALL ON.  Restart if you make changes here.

**(B) Run DISM and SFC**:

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and now test

Then if continued issues:

**(C) Run Windows 10 Repair Install**

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Begin with the option to Keep Everything.  That leaves you where you
> started after repairs have been made.
>
> The next two options (Keep only Data and Keep Nothing) are more
> aggressive.

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the suggestions.  When I updated to 20H2 I didn't have this problem, only with 21H2.  The settings you mentioned were all ON and turning off Password Protected Sharing didn't make any difference.  I don't think there was any corruption issue as sharing is working OK now - I think the update just changed some of the settings and I'm mostly wondering which settings a Pro update would most likely change to some default setting?  Obviously, it changed the Network ID setting.

Comment: 20H2 was a while back and no problems before that or after that (21H1 and now 21H2). If you went directly from 20H2 to 21H2 that would have introduced a number of changes.